# How to dropdown select in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, dropdown

how to do dropdown select in rails form ?

i tried to

```
<div class="field">
     <%= f.label :car_id %>
    <%= select("car", "car_id", @cars) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :firstname %>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :lastname %>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :dateofbirth %>
    <%= f.date_select :dateofbirth %>
  </div>
```

but i get this error

```
undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass
```

at this line.

```
  <%= select("car", "car_id", @cars) %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
<%= f.select :car_id, @cars.collect { |car| [car.name, car.id] } %>
```

You need to set the `@cars` instance variable in the controller method for the above line of code to work.

I am assuming that `car` has a `name` field. Replace `name` with a field of your `Car` model that is good enough for a label.

For every option in the `select`list, `name` will be set as the label and `id` will be set as the `value`.

For more, read the documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/select)

Comment: For the downvoter: Can you please tell me what's wrong with my answer? I am curious to know.

Comment: Thank u for your answer i tried but not worked, so btw it's not me who down voted :)

Comment: the same error undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @user3348410  Try this `<%= f.select :car_id, Car.all.collect { |car| [car.name, car.id] } %>` If you don't have a `name` field in your `cars` table, replace it with a different field from your `cars` table. You are getting that error because `@cars` is `nil` as you haven't set it in the controller method.

Comment: @user3348410 I am glad it worked. Add `@cars = Car.all` in the controller method. Now, you can use `@cars.collect { |car| [car.name, car.id] }` in the view.

Comment: I get now error :/ 1 error prohibited this register from being saved:
Car must exist

Comment: @user3348410 Looks like you didn't select a car from the dropdown.

Comment: @user3348410 Probably, you didn't add `car_id` to the list of `strong`(permitted) parameters. I would suggest you to create a new question with the controller code.

Comment: This is awesome